# How to get videos uploaded by user using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm developing an application to show videos and images from facebook by using the Graph API. I've followed the Graph API document and able to show all images. But in the case of videos I'm getting only the videos where the user is tagged-in.

I need to get the user uploaded videos too. 
How can I get the videos?

The Graph explorer link : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/APP_ID/?method=GET&path=me%2Fvideos&version=v2.3&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some changes in the Graph API calls I've found the solution.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=USER_ID%2Fvideos%2Fuploaded&version=v2.3&

This'll help us to get all the uploaded videos.Where USER_ID is the id of the user who's signed in.

Comment: it also show deleted video. how can remove deleted video?

Answer (score 1):

/me/videos should return all videos, tagged and uploaded.  You can restrict to one or the other by using the type parameter:  /me/videos?type=uploaded

Comment: I've tried both methods but still the problem is there. The response is as follows  {
  "error": "Invalid response"
}

Comment: When I tried with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=USER_ID%2Fvideos%2Fuploaded&version=v2.3&

I've got the correct response which I needed.
Thankz